# Enter key issue in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, newline

I have a column that is defined as a `nvarchar(100)`.

Sometimes office users press enter key wrongly and it causes problems in some applications. When I check the value it seems like **double space character** in SQL Server. Now my mission is finding the records that has this situation. I tried the code below to find the problematic records:

```
DECLARE @NewLineChar AS CHAR(2) = CHAR(10) + CHAR(13);

SELECT * 
FROM TBLCASABIT 
WHERE CARI_ISIM LIKE '%'+CHAR(10) + CHAR(13)+'%'
```

but it doesn't return the records I need.

If I use **double space character** I can see the test record I put and some other records has double space character. So I can't be sure if other records have the same situation or not.

How can I handle this situation? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What is the "double space character"?  AFAIK there is only newline, carriage return, line feed, etc., or combinations of these.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen  "  " (two times whitespace character)

Comment: What records are being returned by your current query?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen with the querry i mensioned above returns nothing.

Comment: Can you please copy your row data with enter character value, so easy work on it

Comment: @SandipPatel test data appears like that in sql server

DENEME  DENEME  GGGGGGF

it has 3 lines normally but appears in one line with 2 whitespaces

Comment: copy sql server data here

Comment: @SandipPatel Sorry but i didnt understand what u mean with that. I have 6033 rows so here you can't paste all the data but i put some of them. They seem like that
DENEME  DENEME  GGGGGGF
DENÝZ SU ve ATIKSU ARITIMI  ÝNÞ. TÝC. SAN.
DIYAR MAK. VE VÝNÇ SAN. TÝC.  A.Þ.
DIYARBAKÝR ÝÇKÝ FABRÝKASI  MÜDÜRLÜGÜ
DÖRTEL TEKSTÝL  SAN.TÝC.A.Þ.
DOSTEL  LTD.ÞTÝ.
DOÐANSOY  MERMER
DSI 21 BÖLGE MÜDÜRLÜGÜ  TRABZON

it makes the same behavior here. they are rows but puts them in one line

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are getting the order of `CHAR(10)` and `CHAR(13)` backwards.  Here is what each of these characters is:

```
CHAR(13) - carriage return, or \r
CHAR(10) - line feed, or \n
```

In Windows, `\r\n` is a line ending, while in Unix `\n` by itself is interpreted as a line ending.  So you should be searching for `CHAR(13)` followed immediately by `CHAR(10)`, and not the other way around.  Try the following query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TBLCASABIT 
WHERE CARI_ISIM LIKE '%' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + '%'
```

**References:**

- [MSDN Social](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/a87b9fbb-40dc-4a2e-83df-eab150620122/difference-between-char13-and-char10?forum=transactsql)
- [DOS vs. Unix Line Endings](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~krueger/csc209h/tut/line-endings.html)

Comment: I have tried that also but still same :( no record returns. I see benefit to tell this also. The test record we inserted from the application they use appears with 2 white space in same line. Maybe its about the datatype which defined in the table.

Comment: Have you made any effort to even check what type of whitespace is in there?

Comment: Yes I have tried text data type also and still same. seems like SQL doesn't let you use newline

Comment: Find a record which should match, then dissect it character by character until you discover for what pattern you should be searching.  This is the only path to a solution for you.  Continuing to post here won't help at all, because we don't have your data.

Comment: Yes i will try that now. I will substring the test data result and try with it. I hope it works. Thanks for your helps Tim.